# Embedding metamask or a wallet on a network in a webpage

Tags: metamask, wallets, network

just a random thought. Is it possible to embed a wallet on a network in a webpage? Sort of like moving part of metamask and making it a permanent built-in module in a webpage. This way, users do not need to switch back and forth networks. The webpage is strictly enforced to be connected with a network. People can even create new wallet addresses directly on the webpage.

Comment: Your idea is great, but I don't think it will work. It's very unsafe

Comment: I'm hoping someone or even Metamask could make it a product and make it safe.

Answer (score 0):

https://web3auth.io/ has a torus wallet. And they have a social account orientd wallet.